# Is there a propper Cuthill Mckee reordering for R?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, bandwidth

I have a Lagrangian matrix with the following sparsity structures:

This is the matrix sparsity structure

[image: This is the matrix sparsity structure]

I want to use the Cuthill Mckee ordering, but I can't really figure out how to use it in R. 
I found 2 possible algorithms:

- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RBGL/versions/1.48.1/topics/Ordering
  But this one asks for a graph rather than a matrix
- https://rdrr.io/bioc/netprioR/man/cuthill_mckee.html but R says it can't find it and entering ??cuthill_mckee into R gives a blank page.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

The function should be available after installing and loading the netprioR package. It seems it is not exported, though, so you would have to call it like `netprioR:::cuthill_mckee(x)`.

From the source code of that package:

```
#' Cuthill McKee (CM) algorithm
#' 
#' Transform sparse matrix into a band matrix
#' 
#' @author Fabian Schmich
#' @import Matrix
#' @param x Input matrix
#' @return Band matrix
cuthill_mckee <- function(x) {
  degs <- data.frame(Idx=1:ncol(x), NonZero=apply(x, 1, function(x) length(which(x != 0))))
  R <- degs$Idx[which.min(degs$NonZero)]
  i <- 1
  for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {
    Ai <- setdiff(which(x[R[i],] != 0), R)
    if (length(Ai) > 0) {
      Ai <- Ai[order(degs$NonZero[Ai], decreasing = FALSE)]
      R <- append(R, Ai)
    } else {
      R <- append(R, degs$Idx[-R][which.min(degs$NonZero[-R])])
    }
    i <- i + 1
  }
  rR <- rev(R)
  return(x[rR, rR])
}
```

Comment: i cannot seem to install the netprioR package. when i enter
install.packages('netprioR') it returns
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘netprioR’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)

Comment: netprioR is on Bioconductor (http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/netprioR.html), so try to install with `BiocManager::install("netprioR")`.